# xgettext won't scan plural form

Tags: php, internationalization, gettext, xgettext, plural

I use Poedit for my gettext i18n and that works fine. I use ZF2 where there are view helpers to integrate the translations. One is `translate`, the other `translatePlural`.

Usage:

```
<?php echo $this->translate('Welcome') ?>
<?php echo $this->translatePlural('Item', 'Items', $number) ?>
```

In Poedit I add the keywords `translate` and `translatePlural`. The normal translations work fine, but for the plural forms, only the "Item" is found (and not the "Items"). Just for testing purposes, I replaced the `$this->translatePlural()` call with `ngettext()`, but I end up with the same result. My conclusion: (my version of) Poedit is unable to scan plural forms.

What should I enter as keyword to let Poedit scan the second string as well?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After some further search, I stumbled upon the syntax `[function]:1,2`. That did the trick for me. I have now identified these two functions as keywords for Poedit as follows:

```
translate
translatePlural:1,2
```

And now my second argument is scanned.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Note that in order to get both to work, you can use the `--keyword` argument more than once in the same function call.